# Why does std::assignable_from return false?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm using Apple Clang and have the following code in C++:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int x;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
};

struct Bar {
    double x;

    Bar& operator=(const Foo& foo) {
        this->x = static_cast<double>(foo.x);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    static_assert(std::assignable_from<Bar&, const Foo&>, "fail");
    return 0;
}
```

I have defined an assignment operator in `Bar` to assign from `Foo`. However, `std::assignable_from<Bar&, const Foo&>` still returns `false`, causing the static assertion to fail. My understanding is that `std::assignable_from<Bar&, const Foo&>` should return `true` since `Bar` objects can be assigned from `Foo` objects due to the custom assignment operator I defined in `Bar`.

I'm compiling this with Apple Clang. Could this be a compiler issue or am I misunderstanding how [`std::assignable_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/assignable_from) works? Could someone explain why `std::assignable_from<Bar&, const Foo&>` returns `false` and how I could correct this?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8nYsedrss

Comment: Note that `is_assignable_v` is true, but that the concept also expects the two objects to be equal after assignment.

Comment: @BoP What does it mean for two object to be equal if no equality operator is defined for them?

Comment: It also `requires common_reference_with`, which is IMO questionable. Is it a defect or a feature?

Comment: In the meantime, `std::is_assignable_v` from `<type_traits>` should work.